# In Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop what does "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" actually encrypt?

Tags: encryption

When installing Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop with the GUI there is a screen where you can choose "Erase disk and Install Ubuntu" with an "Advanced features..." button. If you click that button, you can select "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu installation" and "Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security". What exactly does that encrypt, the boot partition, the Home folder, the entire hard drive or something else?

Comment: AFAIK, [these answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429590/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-the-new-encryption-feature-in-ubuntu-13) are still valid. I can't think of anything that has fundamentally changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

It encrypts the whole partition which Ubuntu is installed on. For more detailed answer, see this: [What are the advantages/disadvantages of the new encryption feature in ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429590/what-are-the-advantages-disadvantages-of-the-new-encryption-feature-in-ubuntu-13)